# define public method that return data in twitter bootstrap plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

How can I define public methods in twitter bootstrap plugin that return data?
For example I have this snippet:

```
  var Button = function (element, options) {
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.button.defaults, options)
  }

 /* BUTTON PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ======================== */

  $.fn.button = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('button')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('button', (data = new Button(this, options)))

      if (option == 'toggle') data.toggle()
      else if (option) data.setState(option)
    })
  }
```

I would want something like this:

```
 var text = $('button.general').button().getTextLabel();
```

It would return an array of text for each button that has .general class and plugin applied

Answer (score 0):

The form that you want to put the query in (`$('button.general').button().getTextLabel()`) is going to *apply* the plugin on every element selected, so I don't know how useful that would be. Moreover, it seems unnecessary to hack the plugin source to add this functionality, since you will have to check if the element has the Button data anyway.

Rather I would suggest something along the lines of:

#### JavaScript

```
var text = $('button.general')
  .filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('button');
  })
  .map(function (i, el) {
    return $(el).text();
  })
```

For example, running the above on the Bootstrap Documentation page, using the selector `.btn` instead of `button.general`, yields the array

```
["Left", "Middle", "Right", "Left", "Middle", "Right"]
```